# MS Teams: navigate to chat message via link

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Does MS Teams provide a possibility to navigate to a specific chat message via the link? For example, I want that after clicking a link my chat scroll to the message pointed by the link.

Maybe deep links can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@John Walker Yes, it is possible to deeplink to a channel message from a bot. But currently we do not have any document to share with you. Could you please try getting the link of a message in the channel using "Copy link" (see the image attached to get link) and use that format to generate your deeplink?
[image]

This works only for channel messages. Currently, there is no way to deeplink to a 1:1 message.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure: it works only for Teams, not for Chats, right?

Comment: Yes. It works only for channel messages but not personal chat messages.